# Audio Conexant CX20753/4 only outputs to internal speaker if i reboot from Windows, headphones doesn't work

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, alsa, headphones

If I start Ubuntu from a cold boot, Internal audio, and Headphones work flawlessly.

But if I start Windows and I reboot to Ubuntu, only **internal speakers** work, no matter how much I connect and disconnect it from my laptop, the audio comes out of the speakers and not through the headphones **even when they are connected**.

Here are my logs and dumps:

Common info (There is the kernel info, the audio, and kernel modules):

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CX20753/4 Analog [CX20753/4 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0


00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 150
    Region 0: Memory at e1420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Region 4: Memory at e1410000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=55mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee004d8  Data: 0000
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_soc_skl, snd_soc_avs


snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     81920  1
snd_ctl_led            24576  0
snd_hda_codec_conexant    28672  1
snd_hda_codec_generic   102400  1 snd_hda_codec_conexant
snd_soc_avs           131072  0
snd_soc_skl           176128  0
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_hda_ext_core       36864  3 snd_soc_avs,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_ipc        20480  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_sst_dsp        36864  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    69632  1 snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_soc_skl
snd_soc_core          368640  3 snd_soc_avs,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  3 snd_soc_avs,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_skl
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         176128  6 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_soc_avs,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core          114688  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_soc_avs,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               155648  10 snd_soc_avs,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_skl,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
ledtrig_audio          16384  3 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,thinkpad_acpi
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            45056  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                77824  9 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_dummy
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd                   114688  22 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec_conexant,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_compress,thinkpad_acpi,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd


Linux thinkpad-e580 5.19.0-35-generic #36~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb 17 15:17:25 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

- When I cold boot to Ubuntu (shutdown laptop, power on, and boot to Ubuntu):

Dump:

```
Codec: Conexant CX20753/4
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x14f15111
Subsystem Id: 0x17aa5068
Revision Id: 0x100101
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold S3D3cold CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=3, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
Node 0x10 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xc1d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Headphone Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="CX20753/4 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x46 0x46]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x60]: 44100 48000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x11 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xc1d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Speaker Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x60]: 44100 48000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x12 [Beep Generator Widget] wcaps 0x70000c: Mono Amp-Out
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x07, nsteps=0x07, stepsize=0x0f, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x03]
Node 0x13 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Device: name="CX20753/4 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x50 0x50] [0x50 0x50]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x18 0x1a* 0x19
Node 0x14 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x19* 0x1a 0x15
Node 0x15 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20050b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10 0x11
Node 0x16 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400581: Stereo
  Pincap 0x0000001c: OUT HP Detect
  Pin Default 0x04211040: [Jack] HP Out at Ext Right
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x4, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0xc0: OUT HP
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x17 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400501: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10 0x11*
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x2f, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00001124: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 80
  Pin Default 0x40f001f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00: VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x2f, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00001124: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 80
  Pin Default 0x04a11030: [Jack] Mic at Ext Right
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=02, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Internal Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x2f, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x02 0x02]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x95a60120: [Fixed] Mic at Int Top
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1b [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x1c [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
```

Screenshots from HDA Jack Retask:
[image: Basic View]
[image: Advanced View]

- When I reboot from Windows to Ubuntu:

Dump:

```
Codec: Conexant CX20753/4
Address: 0
AFG Function Id: 0x1 (unsol 1)
Vendor Id: 0x14f15111
Subsystem Id: 0x17aa5068
Revision Id: 0x100101
No Modem Function Group found
Default PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xe]: 16 20 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
Default Amp-In caps: N/A
Default Amp-Out caps: N/A
State of AFG node 0x01:
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 D3cold S3D3cold CLKSTOP EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
GPIO: io=3, o=0, i=0, unsolicited=1, wake=0
  IO[0]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[1]: enable=0, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=0
  IO[2]: enable=1, dir=0, wake=0, sticky=0, data=0, unsol=1
Node 0x10 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xc1d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Control: name="Master Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Master Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Device: name="CX20753/4 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x3d 0x3d]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x11 [Audio Output] wcaps 0xc1d: Stereo Amp-Out R/L
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x80 0x80]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  PCM:
    rates [0x560]: 44100 48000 96000 192000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x12 [Beep Generator Widget] wcaps 0x70000c: Mono Amp-Out
  Control: name="Beep Playback Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Control: name="Beep Playback Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=1, dir=Out, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-Out caps: ofs=0x07, nsteps=0x07, stepsize=0x0f, mute=0
  Amp-Out vals:  [0x03]
Node 0x13 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Control: name="Capture Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Control: name="Capture Switch", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=2, ofs=0
  Device: name="CX20753/4 Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x80 0x80] [0x50 0x50] [0x50 0x50]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x18 0x1a* 0x19
Node 0x14 [Audio Input] wcaps 0x100d1b: Stereo Amp-In R/L
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x50, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a] [0x4a 0x4a]
  Converter: stream=0, channel=0
  SDI-Select: 0
  PCM:
    rates [0x160]: 44100 48000 96000
    bits [0xa]: 16 24
    formats [0x1]: PCM
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 3
     0x19* 0x1a 0x15
Node 0x15 [Audio Mixer] wcaps 0x20050b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x4a, nsteps=0x4a, stepsize=0x03, mute=1
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00] [0x00 0x00]
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10 0x11
Node 0x16 [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x17 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x400501: Stereo
  Pincap 0x00000010: OUT
  Pin Default 0x90170110: [Fixed] Speaker at Int N/A
    Conn = Analog, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x1, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x40: OUT
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x18 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40058b: Stereo Amp-In
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x2f, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x0000113c: IN OUT HP Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 80
  Pin Default 0x40f001f0: [N/A] Other at Ext N/A
    Conn = Unknown, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0xf, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x00: VREF_HIZ
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
  Connection: 2
     0x10* 0x11
Node 0x19 [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x2f, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x00 0x00]
  Pincap 0x00001124: IN Detect
    Vref caps: HIZ 80
  Pin Default 0x04a11030: [Jack] Mic at Ext Right
    Conn = 1/8, Color = Black
    DefAssociation = 0x3, Sequence = 0x0
  Pin-ctls: 0x24: IN VREF_80
  Unsolicited: tag=01, enabled=1
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1a [Pin Complex] wcaps 0x40048b: Stereo Amp-In
  Control: name="Internal Mic Boost Volume", index=0, device=0
    ControlAmp: chs=3, dir=In, idx=0, ofs=0
  Amp-In caps: ofs=0x00, nsteps=0x03, stepsize=0x2f, mute=0
  Amp-In vals:  [0x02 0x02]
  Pincap 0x00000020: IN
  Pin Default 0x95a60120: [Fixed] Mic at Int Top
    Conn = Digital, Color = Unknown
    DefAssociation = 0x2, Sequence = 0x0
    Misc = NO_PRESENCE
  Pin-ctls: 0x20: IN
  Unsolicited: tag=00, enabled=0
  Power states:  D0 D1 D2 D3 EPSS
  Power: setting=D0, actual=D0
Node 0x1b [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
Node 0x1c [Vendor Defined Widget] wcaps 0xf00000: Mono
```

Screenshots from HDA Jack Retask:
[image: Basic view]
[image: Advanced View]

- Changes between cold boot to Linux and reboot from Windows:

Diff: https://pastebin.com/q6jBNDgB

Screenshot with color output from terminal: [image: Diff Color]

Can it be a kernel-related bug about this?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: A couple of things. 1. Please do not show pictures of the terminal contents. Cut and paste the info into the body of the text. 2. It reads like Windows is not shutting down and is in suspend or hibernate. This can cause the hardware to think it is still in use and you get this type of result.  Start Windows and make sure it is fully and completely shutdown. What are the exact steps you use to go from Windows to Ubuntu?

Comment: 1.Shutdown Windows completely (with fast startup feature disabled).

2.Force shutdown laptop before booting any OS and turn on again. (i do this step if i shutdown with fast startup feature or reboot windows)

3.Boot Ubuntu using F12 boot menu. 

It works without problem if i do it that way.